# Password during install does not work

Tags: password

I just installed an Ubuntu 20.04 on a VM managed by VirtualBox.
I set-up a password, but I couldn't login with it after the installation, "wrong password".

I re-installed the OS and checked the box "login automatically".

Now, I can login in the computer, because it's automatic, but I can't change the password, I can't use sudo or su because "the password is wrong"

I checked on a text editor and there is no keyboard problem, this is the right password.

I found some subjects about this one year ago, and people said to disable the auto-login, but it was disabled the first time. I don't want to be locked on the first screen again ><"

What should I do ?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Hi !

Yes it was, I tested my password during the keyboard configuration step

Comment: Hey juliensl! I suggest you to back up your files, reinstall the OS in VM and use a simple password for the time being. Note down the password somewhere in a book. I guess that might help. After some time, you can change your password to a more complex one. And don't forget the complex password. I also suggest you to take a snapshot in VirtualBox before changing the password to a complex one. In case if you forget the complex password, you can return to the previous simple password using the snapshot. BTW, I suggest you to go through the [tour] page. If you reply to my comment, tag me @Random.

Comment: Hi @Random ! 
Thank you for your answer and sorry to have not answer before, I didn't have my computer.

I re-install it again, try a very simple password "a", but it still does not working :( 
I test the password just before (in my name), there is no keyboard settings.
During the login, I show the password, this is a good "a", but it does not work.

What should I do ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this process to reset the password :
https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-reset-root-password

It works now :)

I don't know why it does not work during the install... But the problem is solved !

Have a good day

Comment: Hey juliensl! I would like to quote from [the help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer): *"Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline."*